# question about PORT

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have written a program in C# that sends text to COMx.

I wish to test it using HyperTerminal, meaning I want to read the text that I send with my program. When I set the WAIT FOR CALL in HyperTerminal, my program is refused access to the given port.

How can I test my program? Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you should read the etiquette applied to emails, irc chatrooms, posting to forums, to using uppercase as that is considered SHOUTING! The likelihood of shouting like THAT would mean your question would get ignored or closed!

Comment: "it means i wanna read the text that i send by my program . but when i set the WAIT FOR CALL in... "....



why do you want to read the text, which you yourself send ?

Comment: @tommieb75 - Normally I'd agree with you, but only key words were capitalized, not the entire post.  I've edited it to make it a little more palatable for everyone.

Comment: hi 
i have problem in programing not in writing a text 
you can help me or no?

Comment: 7 questions about serial ports, really?

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can give is that the serial port is locked by your program and hence HyperTerminal cannot access the port as it is in use by your program. The best thing is to use a null modem cable loopback device in which you can send data and it will get looped back, like what EricLaw suggests.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Answer (score 1):

tommieb75 and EricLaw's answers are both right. When an application opens a serial port, the port is opened exclusively and no other app can work with it.

In order to test my serial applications I always use [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/). You can create a pair of virtual linked serial ports and setup your app to write to one of them and the HyperTerminal to listen to the other one.

This tool has helped me countless times. I strongly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to put a null-modem DB9 cable from COM1 to COM2 and use COM2 to talk to COM1.

Comment: He would need a null-modem cable, not a pass-through cable.

Answer (score 0):

Take your serial cable and solder in on your RX or TX side of the COM port. Now, connect this to another COM port on your PC. Tada - now you can monitor what you are sending or receiving on this port by listening in on the other. Don't terminate TX on this other COM port so you don't disturb this connection. I have a couple of these cables in the office for this very purpose. I don't trust Serial Port monitoring software.

Comment: this instruction sounds like it's missing a couple words?